# Using select from another select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the following query where I will have finally a 205 patient IDs to work with:

```
select 
    patient_id
FROM
    visit
WHERE
    month(visit.date_of_visit)=3 
    AND 
    year(visit.date_of_visit)=2018
    AND
    visit.visit_status='Active'
GROUP BY patient_id
```

I want to get all the 205 IDs and run them into other query to see how many diseases we have as cardio-vascular and then as respiratory disease.

My database structure is as the following:

[image]

What I want is to get for each patient id, what they are diagnosed at ONLY their first visit to the hospital (so here we will work with `min(visit.date_of_visit)`)

The desired result for `diagnosis_name LIKE '%Cardio%':

E.g>:

> Patients: 150 (Or something)

And the query is changed to get the respiratory info.

I tried the following for the Cardio diseases where I use select from select:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
(
select 
    min(visit.date_of_visit), visit_id, patient_id, count(*) as patientId
FROM
    visit
WHERE
    month(visit.date_of_visit)=3 
    AND 
    year(visit.date_of_visit)=2018
    AND
    visit.visit_status='Active'
GROUP BY patient_id
) as vid
LEFT JOIN
consultation ON consultation.visit_id=vid.visit_id
LEFT JOIN
diagnosis ON diagnosis.diagnosis_id=consultation.diagnosis_id
WHERE  diagnosis.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Cardio%'
```

The result was: `5` which is a wrong number.

This can be done easily with PHP and MYSQL together but this will exhaust the server by repeating the same query for 205 times and increment a counter. So the desired result should be only done with MySQL.

Data example:

**Visit Table**

> visit_id= 1; date_of_visit=2018-03-03; visit_reason=Active; ...;
>   patient_id=1234;
>
> visit_id= 2; date_of_visit=2018-03-04; visit_reason=Active; ...;
>   patient_id=1239;
>
> visit_id= 3; date_of_visit=2018-03-07; visit_reason=Active; ...;
>   patient_id=1234;

**Consultation Table**

> consultation_id=1; ...; diagnosis_id=12; visit_id=1;...;
>
> consultation_id=2; ...; diagnosis_id=12; visit_id=2;...;

**Diagnosis Table**

> diagnosis_id=12; diagnosis_name: hypertension (cardio disease);
>
> diagnosis_id=13; diagnosis_name: renal disease

By running the query to see patients who came to hospital and that they were diagnosed as having cardio disease in their initial first visit, the result should be in the example as **2** as you can see from the example where patient_id=1234 had 2 visits but I need to know what he had in his first one.

Comment: Would you like to add sample data (as text) to your question?

Comment: Yes. Just give me few minutes.

Comment: And expected output (as text) based on the example data.

Comment: Done. You can see the example.

Comment: badly formatted example data will cost us a lot off time to work with.. Can you make it a ascii based data -> https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ it you make it ascii based we can simply use sqlfiddle.com ascii importer to generate create and insert statements... Or use mysql-workbench export function to generate CSV from your data -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html

Comment: I'm not clear about your data - 1234 and 1239 were diagnosed with hypertension on their first visit so I would expect the result to be 2 is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in MySQL 8+.  But in older versions you need to calculate the value some other way.

The question for you is what you are counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_diagnoses, COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) as num_patients
FROM visit v JOIN
     (SELECT patient_id,
             MIN(v.date_of_visit) as min_dov
      FROM visit v
      WHERE v.date_of_visit >= '2018-03-01' AND
            v.date_of_visit < '2018-04-01' AND
            v.visit_status = 'Active'
     ) vf
     ON v.patient_id = vf.patient_id AND v.date_of_visit = vf.min_dov JOIN
     consultation c
     ON c.visit_id = v.visit_id JOIN
     diagnosis d
     ON d.diagnosis_id = c.diagnosis_id
WHERE d.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Cardio%';
```

When working with dates, it is best to compare column values directly to dates, rather than dissecting them.

Answer (score -1):

It works fine, test it now on the live scenario.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
(
    select 
        min(visit.date_of_visit) first_date,  patient_id, count(*) as patientId
    FROM
        visit
    WHERE
        month(visit.date_of_visit)=3 
        AND 
        year(visit.date_of_visit)=2018
        AND
        visit.visit_status='Active'
    GROUP BY  patient_id
) as vid
INNER JOIN  visit b ON
      B.patient_id    =   vid.patient_id AND
      B.date_of_visit =   vid.first_date and
      month(B.date_of_visit)=3         AND 
      year(B.date_of_visit)=2018       AND
      B.visit_reason='Active'

INNER JOIN consultation ON 
    consultation.visit_id   =   B.visit_id

INNER JOIN diagnosis ON 
    diagnosis.diagnosis_id  =   consultation.diagnosis_id AND
    diagnosis.diagnosis_name LIKE '%Cardio%'
```

Comment: This will give all records per group not the first record(s) per group.. Because you didn't use the min(visit.date_of_visit) value within the join.

Comment: No, it is not taking the first date of visit

Comment: There are some problems with this code - min(visit.date_of_visit) needs to be aliased and vid.first_date should be vid.alias otherwise it's correct according to my understanding of the question and yields a count of 2

Comment: Yes, min(visit.date_of_visit) alias -> first_date that is used as vid.first_date in a join. you can customize it as you like. if have another query then again contact me. Please make verify my answer if you like. Thanks.